# Jquery validate and submit more forms on one page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

So I am dealing with some survey pages. First my makesurvey.php reads all questions and then create page for editing questions and creating new questions. Each question is in own form and it has own submit. Then admin of survey can on page makessurvey.php fix the existing questions and also can add new question which is subbmited to handlesurvey.php wich makes updates to database.  That means on one page I have let's say 20 forms with submit button. Now I realise that I have encountered more problems. The survey will be handle only by one admin. And this survey apllication needs to work dynamic, because admin can enter some new question, later can delete some questions. After some time add new questions, then delete and so on.

PROBLEMS:

1.Problem: On page makesurvey when admin wants to edit survey how to make just one jQuery function, which will first validate then submmit form to handlesurvey.php. (admin will edit one question at time and press submit). The other option is to generate so many js functions for each form but I think that isn't appropriaty way, but I think it would work fine.
2.Problem: When admin adds/edits some question how should my handlesurvey.php know which variable is in `$_POST[<some_variable>]`.

Generated makesurvey.php page:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
 $("form#updateQuestion").submit(function(){
var SloQuestion = $("#SloQuestion").val();
var typeQuestion=$('#typeQuestion').val();
var RadioValue1=$('#RadioValue1').val();
var RadioValue2=$('#RadioValue2').val();
var RadioValue3=$('#RadioValue3').val();
var RadioValue4=$('#RadioValue4').val();    

//HERE I WILL DO SOME VALIDATION

/*  $.post( "editSurveyHandle.php", $("form#updateQuestion").serialize())
          .done(function( data ) {
          alert("You have changed question!");
   /*     });
       return false;*/
 });      

 </script>
 </head>
 <html>
 <body>
 <form id='updateQuestion1' name='updateQuestion1' method='post' action=''>
 <input type='hidden' name='hidden' value='question1'/><table width='600px'><tr></tr>
 <tr><td width='50%' valign='top'><label for='question1'><h2>CURRENT QUESTION:          </h2></label></td></tr>
 <tr><td>SLOVENIAN </td><td width='50%' valign='top'> <label for='question1'>Some question 1 *</label></td></tr>
 <tr><td width='50%' valign='top'>TYPE QUESTION</td><td width='50%' valign='top'>RADIO BUTTON</td></tr>
 <tr><td><h4>DELETE QUESTION</h4></td><td><input type='checkbox' id='deleteQuestion' name='deleteQuestion' value='delete'/></td></tr>
 <tr><td><h4>CHANGE QUESTIOn</h4></td></tr>
 <tr><td><label>SLOVENIAN</label></td><td><input type='text' id='SloQuestion' name='SloQuestion' size='50' value ='Velikost sobe *'></td></tr>
 <tr><td>TYPE QUESTION </td><td><select id='typeQuestion' name='typeQuestion'>
 <option value='text'>Malo vnosno polje</option>
 <option value='textarea'>Textarea</option>
 <option selected='selected' value='radio'>Izbirino polje</option>
 </select></tr>
 <tr><td></td><td><input type='text' id='RadioValue0' name='RadioValue10' size='50' value ='Bad'></td></tr>
 <tr><td></td><td><input type='text' id='RadioValue1' name='RadioValue11' size='50' value ='Sufficiently'></td></tr>
 <tr><td></td><td><input type='text' id='RadioValue2' name='RadioValue12' size='50' value ='Dobro'></td></tr>
 <tr><td></td><td><input type='text' id='RadioValue3' name='RadioValue13' size='50' value ='Excelent'></td></tr>
 <tr><td></td><td><input type ='submit' id='submit' name='submit' value='Izvedi spremembe'/></td></tr>     
 </table>
 </form> 

 <form id='updateQuestion2' name='updateQuestion2' method='post' action=''>
 <input type='hidden' name='hidden' value='question2'/><table width='600px'><tr></tr>
 <tr><td width='50%' valign='top'><label for='question2'><h2>CURRENT QUESTION:</h2></label></td></tr>
 <tr><td>SLOVENIAN </td><td width='50%' valign='top'> <label for='question2'>Some question 2</label></td></tr>
 <tr><td width='50%' valign='top'>TYPE QUESTION</td><td width='50%' valign='top'>RADIO BUTTON</td></tr>
 <tr><td><h4>DELETE QUESTION</h4></td><td><input type='checkbox' id='deleteQuestion' name='deleteQuestion' value='delete'/></td></tr>
 <tr><td><h4>CHANGE QUESTIOn</h4></td></tr>
 <tr><td><label>SLOVENIAN</label></td>
 <td><input type='text' id='SloQuestion' name='SloQuestion' size='50' value ='Some question 2'></td></tr>
 <tr><td>TYPE QUESTION </td><td><select id='typeQuestion' name='typeQuestion'><option value='text'>Text field</option>
 <option value='textarea'>Textarea</option><option selected='selected' value='radio'>Radio</option></select></tr>
 <tr><td></td><td><input type='text' id='RadioValue0' name='RadioValue10' size='50' value ='Bad'></td></tr>
 <tr><td></td><td><input type='text' id='RadioValue1' name='RadioValue11' size='50' value ='Sufficiently'></td></tr>
 <tr><td></td><td><input type='text' id='RadioValue2' name='RadioValue12' size='50' value ='Dobro'></td></tr>
 <tr><td></td><td><input type='text' id='RadioValue3' name='RadioValue13' size='50' value ='Excelent'></td></tr>
 <tr><td></td><td><input type ='submit' id='submit' name='submit' value='Izvedi spremembe'/></td></tr>
 </table>
 </form>
```

Still editSurvey.php page (I have add two because I can't put all text just in one textarea)

```
 <form id='updateQuestion3' name='updateQuestion3' method='post' action=''>
 <input type='hidden' name='hidden' value='question3'/>
 <table width='600px'><tr></tr>
 <tr><td width='50%' valign='top'><label for='question3'><h2>CURRENT QUESTION:</h2></label></td></tr>
 <tr><td>SLOVENIAN </td><td width='50%' valign='top'> <label for='question3'>Some question 3</label></td></tr>
 <tr><td width='50%' valign='top'>TYPE QUESTION</td><td width='50%' valign='top'>RADIO BUTTON</td></tr>
 <tr><td><h4>DELETE QUESTION</h4></td><td><input type='checkbox' id='deleteQuestion' name='deleteQuestion' value='delete'/></td></tr>
 <tr><td><h4>CHANGE QUESTIOn</h4></td></tr>
 <tr><td><label>SLOVENIAN</label></td><td><input type='text' id='SloQuestion' name='SloQuestion' size='50' value ='Some question 3'></td></tr>
 <tr><td>TYPE QUESTION </td><td><select id='typeQuestion' name='typeQuestion'><option value='text'>Textfield</option>
```

TextareaRadio

And my handlesurvey.php file:

```
 if(isset($_POST["hiddenUpdateQuestion"])){
$username = 'root';
$password='';
$hostname='localhost';
$dbhandle = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password)
or die("Ni se mogoče povezati na MySQL");
$selcetedDB = mysql_select_db("amon_survey",$dbhandle);
mysql_query("set names 'utf8'");

// HERE I WILL ENTER LATER SOME QUERY 
mysql_close($dbhandle);
 }
```

Comment: Dont use mysql, use mysqli instead. why not use jquery form plugin for easy ajax based form posting. It acts like normal form post but by ajax. You can all validation and everything easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your handlesurvey.php:

```
if(isset($_POST["hidden"]))
{
    $username = 'root';
    $password='';
    $hostname='localhost';
    $dbhandle = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password)
    or die("Ni se mogoče povezati na MySQL");
    $selcetedDB = mysql_select_db("amon_survey",$dbhandle);
    mysql_query("set names 'utf8'");

    if($_POST["hidden"]=='question1'){
        //Here will be question1's query;
    }
    if($_POST["hidden"]=='question2'){
        //Here will be question2's query;
    }
}
```

I think it's self-explanatory, comment if something's unclear.

## Edited:

Am sorry, the $_POST was getting the right values, so I assumed the jQuery did too. Please see the updated code below:

In makesurvey.php:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('form').submit(function(e){
       e.preventDefault();
        form_id = (this.id);
        var SloQuestion =$("#"+form_id+" #SloQuestion").val(); // it's basically saying to fetch the input value of the submitted form 
        var typeQuestion=$("#"+form_id+" #typeQuestion").val();
        var RadioValue1 =$("#"+form_id+" #RadioValue1").val();
        var RadioValue2 =$("#"+form_id+" #RadioValue2").val();
        var RadioValue3 =$("#"+form_id+" #RadioValue3").val();
        var RadioValue4 =$("#"+form_id+" #RadioValue4").val();    

        alert(SloQuestion);

    //If custom validation:
        //if(form_id='updateQuestion1')
        //{//validations for #updateQuestion1}
        //if(form_id='updateQuestion2')
        //{//validations for #updateQuestion2}

      $.post( "handlesurvey.php", $("form").serialize())
              .done(function( data ) {
              alert("You have changed question!");
          });       });  
});
</script>
```

## Edited (2nd time):

I'm guessing as per your comment below, you need to know whether the delete question checkbox is checked or not.

You can get to know through:

```
var delVal = $("#"+form_id+" #deleteQuestion ").is(':checked'); 
alert(delVal); //returns true if checked, false if not checked
```

A slight correction, please change your `$.post` to this so that it sends only the submitted form:

```
 $.post( "handlesurvey.php", $("#"+form_id).serialize())
              .done(function( data ) {
              alert("You have changed question!");
          });
```

And on your php:

```
if($_POST["hidden"]=='question1'){

        if(isset($_POST["deleteQuestion"]) && ($_POST["deleteQuestion"]=="delete"))
        {
            //Your delete query for question1
        }
}
    if($_POST["hidden"]=='question2'){

        if(isset($_POST["deleteQuestion"]) && ($_POST["deleteQuestion"]=="delete"))
        {
            //Your delete query for question2
        }
}
```

Comment: This isn't woorking fine, because it allways get first form. <form id='updateQuestion1' name='updateQuestion1' class='updateQuestion1' ....> <form id='updateQuestion2' name='updateQuestion2' class='updateQuestion2' ....> <form id='updateQuestion3' name='updateQuestion3' class='updateQuestion3' ....> ALL OTHERS INPUT FIELAD HAVE SAME NAME IN EACH FORM. How to solve this problem?

Comment: How could I insert pic of code just for checking checkbox value (default value is empty) but if I check I would like to delete this question. So in each form i have this checkbox with uniq id. How to handle this situation. I have tried with: but is not working $(':checkbox').mouseenter(function(){
        if($(this).prop('checked')) {
            $(this).prop('checked', false);
        }
        else{
            $(this).prop('checked', true);
        }

})

Answer (score 1):

You can use some common classes let say "form" for form tag and "input" for each input, textarea or radio. Then loop on each input element validate and send data.

This should be pretty generic:

```
$(".form").submit(function(){
    var data = [];
    var valid = true;

    // get data & validate
    $(this).find('.input').each(function () {
        if ($(this).val().length)
           data[] = $(this).val();
        else
           valid = false;
    });

    if (!valid)
        // set some errors
        return false;

    // send form data ....
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not going to give you the full answer but will guide you.

Step 1: Add a class to the form:

```
<form id='updateQuestion1' class="sq_form" name='updateQuestion1' method='post' action=''>
</form>

<form id='updateQuestion2' class="sq_form" name='updateQuestion1' method='post' action=''>
</form>
```

Step 2: bind onsubmit event to the form using the class selector

```
$(".sq_form").submit(function(event) {
               var indata = $(this).serialize(); //the form data
               //do whatever validations you need to do by using using this keyword
               //Example: $(this).find('input')
});
```